# Vue-Head => How can i change the information in the meta function asynchronously

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

Am trying to change the social sharing meta tags of my website to the data that is coming from the back-end database through an API call

```
head: {
// To use "this" in the component, it is necessary to return the object through a function
title: function () {
  return {
    inner: this.title
  }
},
meta: function () {
  return [
     { name: 'description', content: this.meta.description, id: 'desc' },
     { name: 'application-name', content: this.meta.application_name },
    // Twitter
    { name: 'twitter:title', content: this.title },
    // with shorthand
    { n: 'twitter:description', c: this.meta.description },
    // Google+ / Schema.org
    { itemprop: 'name', content: this.meta.application_name },
    { itemprop: 'description', content: this.meta.description },
    // Facebook / Open Graph
    { property: 'fb:app_id', content: '150240095600075' },
    { property: 'og:title', content: this.title },
    // with shorthand
    { p: 'og:image', c: 'http://jekalowa.com/static/favicon.png' }
  ]
}
```

}

then in my method object

```
methods: {
getAsyncData: function () {
  var self = this
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    self.title = self.artist.stagename + ' | ' + self.title
    self.meta: function () {
      return [
         { name: 'description', content: this.meta.description, id: 'desc' },
         { name: 'application-name', content: this.meta.application_name },
        // Twitter
        { name: 'twitter:title', content: this.title },
        // with shorthand
        { n: 'twitter:description', c: this.meta.description },
        // Google+ / Schema.org
        { itemprop: 'name', content: this.meta.application_name },
        { itemprop: 'description', content: this.meta.description },
        // Facebook / Open Graph
        { property: 'fb:app_id', content: '150240095600075' },
        { property: 'og:title', content: this.title },
        // with shorthand
        { p: 'og:image', c: 'http://example.com/static/favicon.png' }
      ]
    }
    self.$emit('updateHead')
  }, 3000)
}
```

}

I want the social sharing meta tags like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google+ and other meta tag information of the page to change when the page has been fully rendered(mounted or loaded) since all the information is coming from the back-end database so that when a user shares the page to Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google+ the image, title, description and information will be that which came from the database.

i get these error when webpack compiles the code:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ;

Comment: if you are trying to parse JSON data then remove the comment symbol //

Comment: @samayo the comment is not the issue because i have remove them. i get the error at this line precisely: self.meta: function () {

Comment: @ERSS Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ERSS where you able to share to social media successfully?

Comment: @mythicalcoder it is not successful thought since vuejs is not server-side rendered. Before the date is populated in the head section the Crawler bot has received a 200 OK and exited because the index.html file is small and loads faster. I resulted in using NuxtJs [https://nuxtjs.org] it's the SSR equivalent of VueJs.

Comment: As long as it's VueJs you can't because it's a SPA framework. I resulted in using NuxtJs [https://nuxtjs.org]

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be an issue here I think:

```
self.title = self.artist.stagename + ' | ' + self.title
self.meta: function () {
```

Don't you have to say:

```
self.meta = function() ... OR { ... } ?
```

I think there is definitely a syntax error here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code at `self.meta:` instead of colon `:` it should be the equals sign `=`.

```
self.meta = function () {
  return [
   {}
  ]
}
```